# Error with getattr

Tags: python

I was going to [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python) but whenever i call my class in my program it gives me this error:TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Can someone help me

Comment: Really need to see the code to be sure, but it sounds like you are calling a member of a class, without the method being a [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a typical situation which produces the problem you describe.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self,x):
        print(x)

foo=Foo()
```

Calling `gettatrr(Foo,'bar')` returns the unbound method, `Foo.bar`.

```
getattr(Foo,'bar')(1)
```

results in

> TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

The method, `Foo.bar`, is called "unbound" because no instance (such as `foo`) is going to be supplied as the first argument when called. After all, how could it when only the class `Foo` was supplied?

On the other hand, if you supply an instance of the class:

```
getattr(foo,'bar')(1)
```

yields

```
1
```

since `foo.bar` is a "bound" method -- `foo` will be supplied as the first argument when `foo.bar` is called.

PS. Your error message says, "...called with **foo** instance ...". Compared with the error message I posted above, it appears your class is called lowercased `foo`. Note that the [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends always naming classes with a capital letter, and instances with a lowercase one. Doing so will help you avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this example:

```
class Foo:
  def bar(self):
    print 'bar'
  @classmethod
  def baz(cls):
    print 'baz'
  @staticmethod
  def qux():
    print 'qux'

def quux():
  print 'quux'
Foo.quux = quux  # note: Foo.quux is a function attribute NOT a method
```

Then you can have different measures of success depending on how you call these:

```
f = Foo()
f.bar()  # works
getattr(f, 'bar')()  # works
getattr(Foo, 'bar')()  # TypeError
getattr(Foo, 'bar')(f)  # works
f.baz()  # works
getattr(f, 'baz')()  # works
getattr(Foo, 'baz')()  # works
```

And so on.  The basic idea at play is that when calling a method, using the syntax `obj.method(...)`, the object itself is passed as the first `self` argument; but when the same callable is addressed as an attribute of the class, then this special substitution is not done.  This applies to the `getattr` function also.